# c++20 partial class specialization with concepts and variadic template args

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, c++-concepts, compiler-bug

Looking to understand why the code below results in:

> class template partial specialization is not more specialized than the primary template

```
template <typename T, std::integral... Us>
struct foo : std::false_type {};

template <std::integral T, std::integral... Us>
struct foo<T, Us...> : std::true_type {};
```

Clearly it's more specialized based on the first template argument, regardless whether remaining variadic arguments are contrained via `std::integral` concept.

#### Version 2 - no contraints on variadic args

In fact, if we remove the contraints from `Us` the specialization takes place as expected:

```
template <typename T, typename... Us>
struct foo : std::false_type {};

template <std::integral T, typename... Us>
struct foo<T, Us...> : std::true_type {};
```

#### Version 3 - single arg with contraint

The same is true if we use a single `U`, even with the contraint present:

```
template <typename T, std::integral U>
struct foo : std::false_type {};

template <std::integral T, std::integral U>
struct foo<T, U> : std::true_type {};
```

#### Version 4 - workaround

I have found a workaround that is functionally equivalent to the code in question:

```
template <typename T, std::integral... Us>
struct foo : std::false_type {};

template <std::integral T>
struct foo<T> : std::true_type {};

template <std::integral T, std::integral U, std::integral... Us>
struct foo<T, U, Us...> : std::true_type {};
```

godbolt link for experimantation with code above: https://godbolt.org/z/9Tn1KeKnK

Is this a bug?

Comment: I highly suspect that version 1 should work and you have run into a compiler bug. MSVC compiles it and if you remove the template parameter pack, it also compiles because `std::integral` obviously makes the partial specialization more constrained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have run into a compiler bug which surprisingly both GCC and clang have. The relevant wording is this:

> A declaration `D1` is more constrained than another declaration `D2` when `D1` is at least as constrained as `D2`, and `D2` is not at least as constrained as `D1`.

- [[temp.constr.order] *more constrained*](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.order#def:more_constrained)

Furthermore, [[temp.func.order] p6.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order#6.4) states:

> Otherwise, if one template is [more constrained](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.order#def:more_constrained) than the other, the more constrained template is more specialized than the other.

The full definition of "more constrained" is somewhat involved, but obviously, having the constraint `std::integral<T>` makes the partial specialization more constrained than the primary template, which has no such constraint.

More formally, the disjunctive normal<sup>(1)</sup> form of the primary template constraint would be<sup>(2)</sup>:

> ```cpp
> (std::integral<U> && ...) // (3)
> ```

The disjunctive normal form<sup>(1)</sup> of the partial specialization constraint would be:

> ```cpp
> (std::integral<U> && ...) && std::integral<T>
> ```

The latter DNF is the former DNF with one additional constraint, therefore, the latter [subsumes](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.order#def:constraint,subsumption) the former.
The partial specialization is more constrained, and therefore more specialized.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>In this case, the DNF is simultaneously the conjunctive normal form because there is no disjunction.</sub>

<sup>(2)</sup> <sub>This is based on [[temp.param] p5](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#5) and [[temp.constr.decl] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.decl#3).</sub>

<sup>(3)</sup> <sub>Interestingly, the fold expression in this DNF is considered to be a single atomic constraint. This detail does not change anything about the answer though.</sub>

### Compiler bugs

Note that MSVC compiles version 1 just fine, as it should. See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/qGb1bdYja). Only GCC and clang fail to compile it.

None of your workarounds (versions 2 through 4) should be necessary.
Note that the behavior or GCC and clang is uttely nonsensical. Even if we add tons of additional constraints, such as

```cpp
requires std::floating_point<T> && (std::floating_point<Us> && ...)
```

... GCC and clang still do not consider this partial specialization to be more constrained. See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WEa7T7Gss).

The clang diagnostics hint at a possible cause for this bug:

> ```
> <source>:14:28: note: similar constraint expressions not considered > equivalent; constraint expressions cannot be considered equivalent unless they originate from the same concept
>    14 | template <std::integral T, std::integral... Us>
>       |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> <source>:11:23: note: similar constraint expression here
>    11 | template <typename T, std::integral... Us>
>       |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

This is presumably because such a *type-constraint* turns int a fold expression, see [Concepts TS Issue 28](http://cplusplus.github.io/concepts-ts/ts-active.html#28). However, regardless of what `std::integral...` is considered to be, the additional constraint `std::integral<T>` should make the partial specialization more constrained.

### Best workaround yet

By avoiding the fold expression issue, which results in utterly nonsensical behavior, we can get GCC and clang to behave well:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
concept all_integral = (std::integral<Ts> && ...);

template <typename T, typename... Us>
requires all_integral<Us...>
struct foo : std::false_type {};

template <std::integral T, typename... Us>
requires all_integral<Us...>
struct foo<T, Us...> : std::true_type {};
```

Perhaps the reason why this works is that GCC and clang otherwise incorporate the constraint on `T` into the fold expression for `Us`, and the entire constraint is thus atomic.

Comment: thanks for more details, it does seem to be connected to how boolean fold expressions are evaluated, from my limited understanding this has been a bug since 5 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843745/how-are-fold-expressions-used-in-the-partial-ordering-of-constraints

Comment: @serine good to know that the type-constraint on the pack turns into a fold expression, and fold expressions are considered to be a single atomic constraint. I'm not sure to what extent this is related, since one template is obviously more constrained regardless of what the constraint on `Us` is exactly.